# Debugging in Codelite (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: codelite

I installed codelite (v4.1.5770) in Ubuntu 12.04.

I find that it cannot build correctly, when the program has errors. It reports them in the process of building, but finally when is finished building, it outputs the message that there is no error.

I've not faced such situation in windows. I changed the building setting but it was useless.

So who can tell me what should I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

codelite uses regular expressions to parse the output produced by the compiler.
It is likely (and this is probably the case) that the error format that the compiler produced simply was not recognized by codelite.

If you could post some of the error messages you got which were not detected as errors / warnings by codelite, I could help you compile a proper regular expressions and instruct you where to place them inside codelite

Eran